# Deleting Users & Unique Email Address

Tags: php, mysql

I'm running a site and the unique element for each user is the email address.

Currently when a user deletes their account or admin deletes it there is a database column "active" that changes from 1 to 0 indicating the account isn't active.

I've now got an issue where users then wanting to join again with the same email address and as it exists and is unique they can't re-use it.

I was planning on doing the following but I wanted to ask the general community to see if there is a better way of performing this requirement.

Idea: On the delete I would rename the email address from "user@example.com" to "user@example.com:::unixtimestamp".

Thoughts?

Comment: Why don't you just set the active column back to 1 to indicate it is active again?

Comment: that could be a good idea actually - I really could use the same existing data... nice... appreciated!

Comment: @Adam The thing that's kind of bad here, is that if a user wants to be deleted, their email shouldn't be kept in the database at all. That would probably break a few privacy policies; I know I wouldn't like it if someone/company did that to me. I would rethink this as you could get into some potential trouble. You need to give them a double opt-in/opt-out option for signup/delete. This should actually be a potential answer to this question.

Answer (score 3):

I'll post [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39008765/deleting-users-unique-email-address#comment65369397_39008765) as a [Community Wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) with some added information.

The thing that's kind of bad here, is that if a user wants to be deleted, their email shouldn't be kept in the database at all.

That would probably break a few privacy policies; I know I wouldn't like it if someone/company did that to me.

I would rethink this as you could get into some potential trouble. You need to give them a double opt-in/opt-out option for signup/delete if you're not already doing that.

Here are a few links you may want to read, and I suggest you do.

- https://www.ftc.gov/tips-advice/business-center/guidance/can-spam-act-compliance-guide-business
- http://www.iubenda.com/blog/privacy-policy-email-newsletter/
- https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/resources/10-email-marketing-spam-laws-you-need-to-know-about
- https://emailmarketing.comm100.com/email-marketing-ebook/can-spam-law.aspx

*On an added note:*

You could optionally offer the user to simply opt-out from receiving mailings while giving them the option to remain in the database.

This would be initially done in a signup form where you give the user (a) checkbox(es) (radios) to select/tick.

**Note,** that checkboxes should **not** be pre-checked as this would violate certain policies. The users themselves **must** tick the checkbox; this way **you did not force their hand** and that they have read and agreed to the terms & agreement/privacy policy document (that I hope you have already).

I know a few things on the subject, since and for example (in my country) the [Canada's Anti-Spam Legislation](http://fightspam.gc.ca/) has that written in a law that was passed in December 2010.

Bulk mailer services such as MailChimp, Constant Contact etc., also have documentation on this when using an opt-in/opt-out method.